# loading data points into 2D array

Tags: python, databricks

I'm trying to write code for reading the data file I've uploaded, loading all data points into a 2D array, and computing the pairwise correlations/correlations between the data points. I can't get them to print. Someone please help.

Use the guidelines below when you work on Part II:

1. First, create an empty array. Call the array data.

   - For each line, extract the three entries and save then in an array,
     call it A.
2. Second, open the file and read it line by line. Review the file
   handling python videos to see how to do that.

   - For each line, extract the three entries and save then in an array,
     call it A.
   - Then append the array A into the array data.
3. Third, convert the data array into a dataframe. This can be done
   using the sc.parallelize() function as shown in the piece of code
   you used in part I.
4. Finally, call the correlation function as also shown in the code
   you used in Part I of the lab:  `corr(data, method="pearson")`

```
from pyspark.mllib.stat import Statistics

import numpy as np
f_path = '/dbfs/FileStore/tables/users_no_labels.txt'
data = np.empty([])
with open(f_path) as f_obj:
  A = f_obj.readlines()
for line in A
  print(line.strip())

distdata = np.append(data, A) 
DATA = sc.parallelize(distdata).collectAsMap()

print(Statistics.corr(DATA[:3], method="pearson"))
```